# How to insert into one column from two table's two different column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got three tables. 
I want to insert below value to table3.stat with "one" sql statement.
 
1.select status from table0, table2 where table0.serial=table2.num
2.select condition from table1, table2 where table1.ID=table2.num
Is it possible with postgresql?

```
table0:
| serial | status |   |
|--------|--------|---|
| a22    | good   |   |
| a33    | bad    |   |
| a11    | bad    |   |

table1:
| ID  | condition |   |
|-----|-----------|---|
| a00 | awesome   |   |
| a44 | bad       |   |
| a11 | bad       |   |

table2:
| num  |   |   |
|------|---|---|
| a00  |   |   |
| a44  |   |   |
| a22  |   |   |
| a33  |   |   |


table3:
| num | stat |
|-----|------|
|     |      |
| -   | -    |

desired result:
| num | stat  |
|-----|-------|
| a22 | good  |
| a33 | bad   |
| a00 |awesome|
| a44 |  bad  |
```

Comment: So what is your desire result ? and what are those empty columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://%20https://rextester.com/JFY22907)**

Use `UNION ALL` even when are two select, is just one statement

```
INSERT INTO table3 ("num", "stat")
select table2."num", table0."status" 
from table0
JOIN table2 ON table0."serial"=table2."num"

UNION ALL

select table2."num", table1."condition" 
from table1
JOIN table2 ON table1."ID"=table2."num"

;
```

Answer (score 0):

seems you are looking for a query as

```
select table2.num, table0.status 
from table0
INNER JOIN table2 ON table0.serial=table2.num
INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.ID=table2.num

insert into table3  (num, stat)
select table2.num, table0.status 
from table0
INNER JOIN table2 ON table0.serial=table2.num
INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.ID=table2.num
```

or if the column don't always  match  you could use left join (as suggested by Juan Carlos Oropeza)

```
select table2.num, table0.status 
from table0
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table0.serial=table2.num
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.ID=table2.num

insert into table3  (num, stat)
select table2.num, table0.status 
from table0
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table0.serial=table2.num
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.ID=table2.num
```

Update

related to your comment

For the inner join you have not valid value in table1  .. so this return no result  .. for left join  .. the the left join return values also  when there is not match  then you have  also null value  .. the unique condition that work

based on you fiddle
 could be

```
select table2."num", table0."status" 
from table0
INNER JOIN table2 ON table0."serial"=table2."num"
LEFT  JOIN table1 ON table1."ID"=table2."num";
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/46bf1/22

Comment: You probably should go with LEFT JOIN

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza  correct answer  updated ..  with your suggestion

Comment: sqlfiddle.com/#!17/46bf1/6

Comment: sqlfiddle.com/#!17/46bf1/11