# Get Previous and Next record from database and loop them

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with IDs from 1 to 8. I want something like this

> If i'm on 4, I should get 3,5
>
> If i'm in on 1, I should get 8,2
>
> If in on 8, I should get 7, 1

Basically looping through the table records

This is my current code

```
-- previous or last, if there is no previous
SELECT *
FROM news
WHERE id < 1 OR id = MAX(id)
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1

-- next or first, if there is no next
SELECT *
FROM news
WHERE id > 1 OR id = MIN(id)
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

But it says *Invalid use of group function*. Any help?

Comment: Are you trying to create a function, a loop or a select?  
    Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: I want a to get the previous and next record. Simple.

Comment: Would be simple if you show sample data and expected output.

Comment: Lets say I have only id field in the table. Would that help?

Comment: something like this. Sample data and expected output https://stackoverflow.com/a/46409126/3470178 or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54890579/how-to-insert-into-one-column-from-two-tables-two-different-column/54907329#54907329

Comment: Why do you get 3,4 (for 4) but not 1,2 (for 1)

Comment: @Strawberry My guess is a typo. for 4 --> `before` should be 3 and `after` should be 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If id is sequential you can do this:

[**SQL DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3be5b/9)

```
SELECT o.id, 
       COALESCE(b.id, (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Table1)) as before_id,
       COALESCE(a.id, (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM Table1)) as after_id
FROM Table1 o
LEFT JOIN Table1 b
  ON o.id = b.id + 1
LEFT JOIN Table1 a  
  ON o.id = a.id - 1
ORDER BY o.id
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| id | before_id | after_id |
|----|-----------|----------|
|  1 |         8 |        2 |
|  2 |         1 |        3 |
|  3 |         2 |        4 |
|  4 |         3 |        5 |
|  5 |         4 |        6 |
|  6 |         5 |        7 |
|  7 |         6 |        8 |
|  8 |         7 |        1 |
```

If ids are not sequential you need use `row_number()` (mysql ver 8+) or session variables to create a sequence.

Comment: The OP wants 3,4 for 4.

Comment: Sorry it was 3,5 for 4

Comment: I find this solution too complicated.  It also makes the assumption that the ids have no gaps.

Comment: @GordonLinoff In my defense I already said assume there are not gaps and require a sequence if there are gaps.

Comment: If there are no gaps, you need no joins.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel How you find previous and next and loop without join?

Comment: You don't need to **find** anything. If there are no gaps, Then you just need `ID - 1` and `ID + 1`. There are only two exceptions, which can be handled with CASE and subquery.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel You are right. But I assume OP also want some other columns beside the ID. The sample queries include `news.*` otherwise as you said would be a trivial query.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you want to show "prev" and "next" buttons, when the user views a news article. I would get the previous and the next ID in the main query, when you fetch the article data:

```
select n.*, -- select columns you need
  coalesce(
    (select max(n1.id) from news n1 where n1.id < n.id ),
    (select max(id) from news)
  ) as prev_id,
  coalesce(
    (select min(n1.id) from news n1 where n1.id > n.id ),
    (select min(id) from news)
  ) as next_id
from news n
where n.id = ?
```

[db-fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j9NDN2Ja64Et1M6nzpoXL1/0)

Now you can use `prev_id` and `next_id` for your buttons, or prefetch the corresponding articles with a simple `select * from news where id = ?` query.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the filtering in your approach and add logic to the `ORDER BY`:

```
(SELECT n.*
 FROM news
 ORDER BY (id < 1), id DESC
 LIMIT 1
) UNION ALL
(SELECT n.*
 FROM news
 ORDER BY (id > 1), id ASC
 LIMIT 1
) ;
```

If you want the `id` values in one row, you can use aggregation:

```
select coalesce(max(case when id < 1 then id end), max(id)) as prev_id,
       coalesce(min(case when id > 1 then id end), min(id)) as next_id
from news n;
```

In both cases, `1` is a sample id and the "1" can be replaced with any value.

Comment: How the second query works to find prev and next? Or is just for row with id 1?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . If the `id` is the minimum, then the first `max()` returns `NULL` and the second is returned.  Otherwise, the "previous" id will be returned from the first `max()`.

Comment: I see now. So only return the prev and max for the row with `id = 1` like a function? In this case `@row_id = 1`